# How to use conditional (if statements) with data from acronyms?

Tags: conditionals, acronyms

I am using acronym for autocomplete my text like mailing functions. So I want the long text from acronym using all the time, and I am using `\acro{}{}` to define, so `\acro{Maria}{f}` - for me shows that the person called Maria is a women and I use `\ac{Maria}` to autocomplete my text. I can't have a good result using any of these functions.

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[dua,nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{a}{f} %f-female m-male
    \acro{b}{}  %none-male a-female
\end{acronym}

\IfStrEq{f}{\ac{a}}{female}{male}

\ifstrequal{\ac{a}}{f}{female}{male}

\ifblank{\ac{b}}{female}{male}

\ac{a}

\ac{b}

\end{document}
```

Answer:

```
male
male
male
f
```

I spected

```
female
female
female
f
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

You need to retrieve the expanded long form of the acronyms and pass it on to the conditionals. Here is one idea (there are a few comments trying to explain the code):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[dua,nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% a macro that expands to nothing if the acronym isn't defined and to the
% long entry else -- it uses the fact that
%
%   \csname fn@<acro key>\endcsname
%
% expands (after two expansions) to two pairs of braces, the first containing
% the short entry and the second containing the long entry;
\newcommand*\aclongentry[1]{%
  % check if the acronym already exists (it does after the second compilation):
  \expandafter\ifx\csname fn@#1\endcsname\relax
    % and either gobble the group after the \fi ...
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    % ... or just remove the braces
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {% two expansions need three (!) \expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    % use the second group containing the long form 
    \@secondoftwo\csname fn@#1\endcsname
  }%
}

% use etoolbox's tests on the long entry of an acronym -- usage:
%
%   \ifaclongtest{<conditional>}{<acro key>}<...>
%
% where <...> depends on the used conditional
\newcommand*\ifaclongtest[2]{%
  % we expand \romannumeral-`0\aclongentry{#2} as argument to
  % the conditional; \romannumeral-`0 triggers full expansion of the argument
  \expandafter#1\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0\aclongentry{#2}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{aaa}{f} %f-female m-male
    \acro{bbb}{}  %none-male a-female
\end{acronym}

aaa: \ifaclongtest{\ifstrequal}{aaa}{f}{female}{male}

bbb: \ifaclongtest{\ifstrequal}{bbb}{f}{female}{male}

aaa: \ifaclongtest{\ifblank}{aaa}{blank}{not blank}

bbb: \ifaclongtest{\ifblank}{bbb}{blank}{not blank}

\end{document}
```

After two compilations this leads to

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was a beginning this time that I posted, but now I am using

```
\newcommand \name \femalemale {f}

\IfStrEq {\femalemale}{f}{female}{male}
```

It solves my question.